# Can't set seconds value of <input type="datetime-local" /> to be 0

Tags: html, datetime, data-binding, blazor

So I have this class which has an attribute Start, of type DateTime.

```
public class ClosedPlatform {

    public DateTime Start;

}
```

What I'm trying to do is bind the Start attribute of a ClosedPlatform instance to an input of type datetime-local.  At the same time I've found that datetime-local inputs don't display DateTime seconds by default, so I'm trying to force it to display the seconds value of Start.

```
ClosedPlatform closedPlatform;

...

<input type="datetime-local" step="1" @bind="@closedPlatform.Start" @bind:format="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"/>
```

I've managed to set up the input to get it almost working.  Setting `step="1"` seems to be the common advice online to get a datetime-local input to display seconds, and it does.  However, my issue is that the input won't let me set the seconds value to be 0.  If the seconds value of closedPlatform.Start is already 0 before the input element is first loaded, then 0 seconds is correctly displayed in the input.  However, if the seconds value is then changed to anything but 0, I can't use the input controls to set it back to 0 again (neither typing it in nor using the up and down controls will work).  If Start has a seconds value of 59 and I increase it by 1, the seconds value shows 0 for a split second before going back to 59 (the same if I try going from 1 down to 0).  Whereas something like say, the minutes value, I can change between a zero and nonzero value just fine.

So I'm wondering is there a way to get a datetime-local input to let me input 0 for the seconds value?  I would have thought more people would have had this issue but I couldn't find any discussion of it anywhere.  I did find out that datetime-local seems like a relatively new input type and is seemingly only fully supported by Chrome, Edge and Opera (I'm using Chrome), so is this just a matter of a newer feature being a bit rough around the edges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Introduction:

First of all, quoting [Mozilla `<input type="datetime-local">` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local):

> Seconds are not supported.

It means, seconds are not supported by control, the control will never set values for `seconds` part. Using `step="1"` has only visual effect.

About your code, to work with dates, you should to remove `seconds` part from bind format, just "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm":

```
<input type="datetime-local"  
       @bind="@closedPlatform.Start" 
       @bind:format="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm" step="1"/>
```

[image: sample]

#### Workaround:

If you want to work with seconds, you need to use a `string` instead a `DateTime` (and use typecasting if you want):

```
<h5>String: @datestr</h5>
<h5>DateTime: @(parseString(datestr))</h5>
<input type="datetime-local" @bind="datestr"  step="1" />


@code {                     

  string datestr = "2013-10-24T20:36:00";

  protected DateTime? parseString(string s)
  {
      ... your code to cast string to datetime
  }
}
```

[image: workaround]

**Disclaimer** Don't try to use this on production, seconds are not supported. Some Internet navigators or devices will don't work with this workaround.

Try it at [blazorfiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/qp60ea2d).